# Change font size for dropdown dojo where options are loaded from a store

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

I'm trying to decrease the font size of all the options in my dijit.form.Select box (dojo 1.6). I'm initializing and setting the options programmatically. How do I change the font size of the options in the dropdown? Please help.

This is my current code:

// MONTH DROP-DOWN DECLARATION

```
        var MONTH = new dijit.form.Select({
            name        : "MONTH",
            options     : store,
            value       : this.fields['MONTH'].value,
            style       : { width: '125px' },
            maxHeight   : -1
        }, this.dapMONTH);
```

(I'm not sure on how to override the CSS theme used)

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't worked with dijit yet, but a simple `font-size: 8pt;` or whatever size you want should propably do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rapti.
But what fontSize : 8pt changes is the size of the option in the widget when a particular value is chosen. What I want here is, when I click the down arrow, all the options in the list should be in a size scaled down to the default size.

Comment: Maybe you should use your browser's inspection tools to determine a proper CSS selector for the options, and then insert `<style type="text/css">selector here {font-size: 8pt;}</style>` into the document header. If that doesn't help, try using `!important`, but it's not a good practice to do this if it is not necessairy.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following CSS:

```
.dijitSelectLabel {
  font-size:30px;      
}
.dijitMenuItemLabel{
    font-size:25px;
}
```

Live example:

https://jsfiddle.net/cz19fcpp/

Where in `.dijitMenuItemLabel` you can handle the font-size for items in the menu list, and in `dijitSelectLabel` you can set font-size for the selected item from the list.